# Hermite polynomials with non standard variance (not equal to one)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

It is known for probabilists that if $p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ then the derivatives of $p$ can be expressed in terms of the Hermite polynomials as follows:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} p(x) = (-1)^n He_n(x) p(x), \quad n\geq 0.$$

My question is the following: if the standard deviation is not one, but $P(\sigma^2,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, is it "easy" to put $\sigma^2$ in the formula? that is, to find an expression for
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} p(\sigma^2, x)=\cdots He_n$$
in terms of the Hermite polynomials maybe evauated at $\frac{x}{\sigma}$ or something.

Thanks a lot!

By the way: my guess is:
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} p(\sigma^2, x)= (-1)^n He_n(\frac{x}{\sigma})\frac{1}{\sigma^n}P(\sigma^2,x).$$

Comment: It should not be necessary to put $\sigma^2$ into the formula. If $f(z)$  denotes an arbitrary pdf, the assumption made is that $f(z)$ has been standardised so that its mean is 0 and variance is 1. Then, if $f(z)$ can be expanded as a series of derivatives of a standard Normal pdf ... you get the Hermite polynomial Gram-Charlier expansion. If you were fitting a data set, you would standardise the data first, do the fit, and then transform back to original units.

Comment: I just want an expression for the $n$-th derivative of $p(\sigma^2,x)$. Nothing really advanced, I have never heard of this Gram-Charlier expansion unfortunately.